# OAuth2 error invalid client

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, google-api

I'm getting an invalid client error. Client works for auth_code.authorize_url, but not for auth_code.get token

relevant code:

```
CLIENT_ID = "$$$.apps.googleusercontent.com"
CLIENT_SECRET = "secret"

REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:3000'
client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, 
                                   site:     'https://accounts.google.com',
                                   token_url: '/o/oauth2/token',
                                   authorize_url: '/o/oauth2/auth')

url = client.auth_code.authorize_url(scope: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds",
                                            redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI)
puts url

code = "taken from url"  #line 20
token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, :redirect_uri => REDIRECT_URI)
```

Error message:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/oauth2-1.0.0/lib/oauth2/client.rb:113:in `request': invalid_client:  (OAuth2::Error)
{
  "error" : "invalid_client"
}
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/oauth2-1.0.0/lib/oauth2/client.rb:138:in `get_token'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/oauth2-1.0.0/lib/oauth2/strategy/auth_code.rb:29:in `get_token'
from oauth.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

One clarification I think I need is that say the code given from the url is `/?code=$code$` do I use just the `$code$?`(currently doing this) or `code=$code$`

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

The answer was the allow offline mode when initializing the client. I was also using a code I had previously used.

changed this:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, 
                               site:     'https://accounts.google.com',
                               token_url: '/o/oauth2/token',
                               authorize_url: '/o/oauth2/auth')
```

to this:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, 
                                   site: 'https://accounts.google.com',
                                   token_url: '/o/oauth2/token',
                                   authorize_url: '/o/oauth2/auth',
                                   additional_parameters: {"access_type" => "offline"} ) #new line
```